# Emacs typing backwards

Tags: debugging

So, sometimes when I go into a buffer that has a `[` as the first character (such as `.ini` files) emacs suddenly starts typing everything backwards. In other words, if I press the keys `y` `e` `s` I get out `s` `e` `y`.

After a little time investigating the behavior it seems that what is actually happening is that after typing any character the cursor immediately jumps to the beginning of the line. This means that if I press `Ctrl+e` after every character I can type forwards. This behavior persists across all buffers once it happens and the only way for me to type normally again is to completely exit out of emacs and restart it.

Does anyone out there have any idea why or how this is happening? For reference, here are my config files https://github.com/blarghmatey/dotfiles/tree/master/home/.emacs.d and the list of packages that are referenced are as follows:

```
ac-capf
ac-inf-ruby
ac-js2
ag
ahg
anaconda-mode
anaphora
ansible
assemblage-theme
async
auto-complete
auto-complete-exuberant-ctags
auto-complete-rst
bundler
chruby
coffee-mode
color-theme
color-theme-approximate
color-theme-monokai
color-theme-sanityinc-solarized
color-theme-solarized
color-theme-twilight
column-marker
command-t
company
company-anaconda
company-inf-python
company-inf-ruby
company-tern
company-ycm
concurrent
css-eldoc
csv-mode
ctable
ctags
ctags-update
cython-mode
dakrone-theme
dark-souls
dart-mode
dash
dash-at-point
dash-functional
deferred
direx
discover
discover-js2-refactor
discover-my-major
distinguished-theme
docean
dpaste
ein
elpy
elscreen
epc
epl
eproject
ess
evil
evil-leader
evil-surround
f
fill-column-indicator
find-file-in-project
findr
flx
flx-isearch
flycheck
flycheck-color-mode-line
fold-this
fringe-helper
fuzzy
gerrit-download
gh
git-commit-mode
git-gutter+
git-gutter-fringe+
git-rebase-mode
goto-chg
haml-mode
helm
helm-ag
helm-aws
helm-cmd-t
helm-company
helm-dash
helm-flycheck
helm-git
helm-proc
helm-projectile
helm-pydoc
helm-spotify
heroku
highlight-indentation
history
idomenu
iedit
inf-ruby
inflections
jedi
jedi-direx
jinja2-mode
js2-mode
js2-refactor
js3-mode
json-mode
json-reformat
json-rpc
json-snatcher
jsx-mode
jump
kivy-mode
late-night-theme
lentic
let-alist
lice
logito
logstash-conf
lush-theme
m-buffer
magit
magit-filenotify
magit-gerrit
magit-gh-pulls
makey
markdown-mode
mkdown
mmm-mode
multi
multi-term
multi-web-mode
multiple-cursors
neotree
nginx-mode
nodejs-repl
nose
org
org-jira
paradox
pcache
pep8
php-mode
pip-requirements
pkg-info
polymode
popup
popwin
powerline
projectile
projectile-rails
puppet-mode
puppetfile-mode
py-autopep8
py-import-check
py-isort
pymacs
python-django
python-environment
pyvenv
rainbow-delimiters
rainbow-mode
rake
request
rinari
ruby-compilation
rvm
s
sass-mode
scss-mode
simple-httpd
skewer-mode
smartparens
smeargle
smex
soothe-theme
sphinx-doc
sr-speedbar
stekene-theme
sx
tern
tern-auto-complete
tree-mode
undo-tree
vagrant
virtualenvwrapper
wakatime-mode
web-mode
websocket
wgrep
wgrep-ag
windata
workgroups2
xlicense
yaml-mode
yasnippet
ycm
zeal-at-point
```

Comment: Something is turning text from left-to-right to right-to-left. Recursively bisect your init file (by commenting out blocks of it using command `comment-region` (`C-u` to uncomment), until you have narrowed down the culprit. If you still have a question about it at that point, then update your question, narrowing it appropriately. IOW, don't just throw a giant sack of stuff out there and ask what's wrong. It is easy and quick to narrow things down yourself - binary search.

Comment: Maybe a little bit more practical approach at locating the reason would be to examine the `current-active-maps` and `post-command-hook` once this happens.

Comment: I am experiencing the same weird behaviour, especially when editing R code inside a knitr Rnw document... any tips? Currently I am forced to kill the buffer and load again from file.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this when editing a `knitr` (.Rnw) code. I believe (but not sure [yet]) that this is due to an update of polymode. I don't know how to call `current-active-maps` or `post-command-hook` (neither shows on `M-x ...`), but if I do `M-x Rnw-mode` then the behavior disappears. Before, my buffer shows `LaTeX/FMP Ref PM-Rnw Fly Compiling` and afterwards it shows `LaTeX/FMP Ref Fly Compiling Noweb NWFL` in case that helps.

Comment: @MariusHofert Did you manage to fix this issue>

Comment: @Omar113 I rarely work with `knitr` anymore, but if the problem appears, I manually do `M-x Rnw-mode`.